# Is there a fix for the bugged playthrough 2 in Borderlands 2?

Tags: xbox-360, borderlands-2

I finished playthrough 2 quests with my friends all out of order and it seems that my playthrough somehow got forever stuck on playthrough 2. I have no story missions left and if I accept new side quests they are not scaled to level 50, like they would be in playthrough 2.5. The last story mission I had to do was "Data Mining", has anyone else encountered the problem and do they know a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

when you are at the main menu hit Y if you are on the xbox and re click to load the character you have already loaded. When it reloads it will ask you if you want to play true vault hero mode or normal mode. Click normal mode and you will be back to play through one and have your situation fixed.